# RNCallKeep.startCall() (Outgoing Call) is not opening IOS Callkit UI

Tags: ios, react-native, voip, callkit, twilio-programmable-voice

I have configured the [react-native-twilio-phone](https://github.com/MrHertal/react-native-twilio-phone) package in my react-native application according to the instructions and also followed the steps properly for [react-native-call-keep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) and [react-native-voip-push-notification](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification).
The problem I am encountering is RNTwilioPhone.startCall("+1XXXXXXXXXX") is not opening the IOS CallKit UI but is able to talk to another end without any problem.

Logs for your reference
[Twilio phone registered and Voip configured properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/turM3.png),
[Logs after calling a phone RNTwilioPhone.startCall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8fk1.png)

Comment: Can you share the relevant code from your application? It's hard to tell what's happening from just the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the react-native-Twilio-phone package and from everything I have gathered, you cannot display the native call UI on an outgoing call on IOS. You must implement your own outgoing call UI on IOS. Someone, please prove me wrong here as I was also wrestling with this same issue a few weeks ago and had to implement my UI which works fine, but I really would also like to use the native UI for outgoing calls.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).